# Accessing datacatalog table in Glue properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I created a table in Athena without a crawler from S3 source. It is showing up in my datacatalog. However, when I try to access it through a python job in Glue ETL, it shows that it has no column or any data. The following error pops up when accessing a column: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '<COLUMN-NAME>'`.

I am trying to access the dynamic frame following the glue way:

```py
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
  database="datacatalog_database",
  table_name="table_name",
  transformation_ctx="datasource"
)

print(f"Count: {datasource.count()}")
print(f"Schema: {datasource.schema()}")
```

The above logs output: `Count: 0` & `Schema: StructType([], {})`, where the Athena table shows I have around ~800,000 rows.

**Sidenotes**:

- The ETL job concerned has `AWSGlueServiceRole` attached.
- I tried Glue Visual Editor as well, it showed the datacatalog database/table concerned but sadly, same error.

Comment: What is your s3 directory structure like ? Can you try adding additional_options = {"recurse": True} to your from_catalog() and try again? Also verify if you have enabled job bookmark and if this is your second run which is failing

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy hey, thanks! Adding recurse=True solved the issue. You can add this as answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the S3 bucket has multiple nested folders inside it. For Glue to read these folders you need to add a flag adding `additional_options = {"recurse": True}` to your from_catalog(). This will help to recursively read records from s3 files.